# Trigger click on URL with hashtag

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hashtag

Can you trigger click on URL with hashtag?

For example:

I have this link: `<a class="contact">Contact Me</a>`

and when I visit `www.example.com/#contact` to fire: `$('a.contact').trigger('click');`

Is this possible by any hacky way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1); // get the hash, and strip out the "#"

if( hash /* && hash === 'contact' */ )  // if there was a hash
    $('a.' + hash ).trigger('click');   //    concatenate it into the selector
```

Comment: I think its what I am trying to achieve. Would you mind updating my fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/ewCQm/ Its the basic structure

Comment: @jQuerybeast: Are you wanting to trigger a jQuery `.click()` handler, or do you intend to have the user follow the link?

Comment: trigger the click sir because it won't be an actual URL. Thank you

Comment: @jQuerybeast: I [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewCQm/2/), but I had to simulate the hash by manually adding it in code. Should work the same if the user actually has `#contact` in the url.

Comment: Maybe here is a better example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/A2ex9/ When the link is clicked, background turns red. If you visit the url with #contact, the background to turn red.

Comment: hmm its pretty much what I was looking for but have a look at this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ewCQm/3/show/#contact You need to visit the site twice so that action happens.  Is it because it has to load jquery first?

Comment: @jQuerybeast: Not sure what you mean by visit it twice. It works for me right away. Anyway, I'd suggest testing it in your actual code instead of jsFiddle just to be sure. The code should definitely not be loaded until jQuery is loaded and the DOM is ready.

Comment: @jQuerybeast: trigger('click') will not activate the href attribute of an anchor, but rather the onclick event for it, which is doing exactly what your saying and changing the background color of the page. You have to perform the redirection in the onclick event.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to capture the `hashchange` event using the [jQuery BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) (see last example on this page). Something along these lines should work:

```
$(window).bind("hashchange", function(e) {
    if ($.param.fragment() === 'contact') {
        $('a.contact').trigger('click');
    }
});

$(window).trigger("hashchange");
```

This should not only work when you first load the page, but also when something else changes the fragment.

Comment: Thank you. I dont intent to use plugins as they bloat out web apps

Comment: I had a different requirement and your code snippet helped me~!