# Run modalbox if in url is mysite.com/#newgoal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to create if I have in my url:

`mysite.com/#newgoal`, my modalbox is displayed?

Currently is displayed if I click button with `id="newGoalButton"`.
I need both options at once.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#newgoal"  id="newGoalButton">New Goal</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#newGoalButton').click(function() {
        $(".fullWhite").fadeIn(100);
        $(".modal").fadeIn(200);
    });
    $('.modal .iks').click(function() {
        $(".fullWhite").fadeOut(200);
        $(".modal").fadeOut(100);
    });
});
```

Comment: you may want to look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887209/trigger-click-on-url-with-hashtag
search better next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var url = window.location.href;
        if (url.indexOf("#newgoal") != -1){
            // display modalbox
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) :

```
$(window).hashchange(function() {
    if (location.hash === '#newgoal') {
        $(".fullWhite").fadeIn(100);
        $(".modal").fadeIn(200);
    }
});
```

And I think you will not need `$('#newGoalButton').click` if you use this: